In PHP. 1GP file takes one-hour time to download from FTP connection. How to increase the download speed?
I PHP fpt connection, I am trying to download one large file minimum 1GP from client server to my server but the downloading time taking minimum one-hour. But the server configuration and bandwidth are higher only. I need to reduce the time maximum 15 to 20 minutes.
<?
// FTP server details
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
$ftp_username = "username";
$ftp_userpass = "password";
$remote_file = "/path/to/remote/file.txt";
$local_file = "/path/to/local/file.txt";

// Establish an FTP connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");

// Login to FTP server
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass)) {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server as $ftp_username\n";

    // Download the remote file and save it to the local file
    if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Successfully downloaded $remote_file to $local_file\n";
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem while downloading $remote_file to $local_file\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Could not login to $ftp_server\n";
}

// Close the FTP connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>

this depends on you internet connection and server bandwidth limit . if your server cannot send more data your high speed internet is useless

Yes. It has been taken care of dedicated internet connection with high speed, server bandwidth and also increased server ram. But the 1GP file takes more than one hour.
